# How to Pass an Element that Triggered an Event and Change a Property of it?

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseevent, this, dom-events

I am trying to change the `background-color` of an `<div>` element. The element triggers an event and calls a function including the element as an argument via `this`.

How do I change the elements properties?

I tried assigning the passed element to a variable and many other trial and error approaches, that I can't recall.

```
newDiv = document.addEventListener('mouseover', doSomething(this));

// Some code here

function doSomething(item)
{
  item.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
}
```

I expect the element's background color to change to `#FFFFFF`, but I get this error message: `TypeError: item.style is undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the function as follow `doSomething(this)` is not ok.  You're actually binding the returned value from function `doSomething`.

The js engine automatically will bind as lexical context the element who triggers the event, so you can use `this` context:

```
this.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
```

Or, you can use the event which is passed as param on the handler:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseover', doSomething);
function doSomething(e) {
   e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It definitely helped me to better understand how this works. I tried ```e.target...``` idea. It only worked after I included this statement  ```if (typeof e === 'undefined') return;``` prior to ```e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';```.